# Why doesn't the lookup program sign invoked instructions with PDA seeds?

Tags: solana-program, signing

Seeing some magic happening in the new `address-lookup-table` program. [Code permalink](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/66d06b3f991a0a6d22f62625e47fc8b100acab24/programs/address-lookup-table/src/processor.rs#L152-L155)

```
invoke_context.native_invoke(
    system_instruction::assign(&table_key, &crate::id()),
    &[table_key],
)?;
```

In this code the `table_key` is the signer, but `table_key` is a PDA. So where are the PD seeds that are usually needed by `invoke_signed`? None of the code in `native_invoke` adds a signature.

Is this some quirk of solana core programs that they can sign for PDAs without the seeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this some quirk of solana core programs that they can sign for PDAs without the seeds?

This is the answer.  When you have direct access to the invoke context in a native (non-BPF) environment, you can do many more things.  This is why the PDA check is done explicitly before these other calls.